# Launch Facebook App from Browser and Post Status Update

Tags: facebook, mobile-safari

I have a mobile website that I would like to allow users to share the url via their native Facebook and Twitter apps (it is tedious to have to login to m.facebook.com).

I can have a link to fb://post to open the FB app, but I can't figure out how to actually pass params for updating a status. I want the functionality of using the sharer.php link on the desktop, but for the native mobile app.

Is this possible?